# My ActionClass in not getting called

Tags: struts2

I want to fetch a text box value from jsp to my action class.

But my action class in not getting called while submitting the page.

My code are

Jsp page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="AddedColor" method="post">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Color Name</span>
                <span class="ib"> <input type="text" name="color" id="color"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <input type="button" id="submit_color" value="Add Color"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In struts.xml

```
<package name="colorpkg" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="AddedColor" class="iland.work.ColorAction" method="insert">
            <result name="success">/pages/colors/showColors.jsp</result>
       </action>
    </package>
```

In ActionClass

```
public class ColorAction extends ActionSupport {       

    private String color;
    //getter and setter of color
    public String insert() {
            System.out.println("-> ColorAction insert()");
            System.out.println(getColor());
            return SUCCESS;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Use Struts2 `<s:form>` or `<s:url>` tags.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use `<s:form>` or `<s:url>`.

Comment: @Manish No, but they have some advantages. All they do is render HTML.

Comment: you've used a normal button instead of a submit button.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for reply. I dont know advantages of using tags. I use it only if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="box">
        <input type="submit" id="submit_color" value="Add Color"/>
</div>
```